# Chrome get "user agent stylesheet"

Tags: css, google-chrome

Google Chrome has a built-in stylesheet with default margins, paddings, etc.

Is there a posibility to get this **"user agent stylesheet"** to see what are the **default** chrome css settings?

*I know that I need to override it or use reset style, but I just want to get this chrome built-in css*

Comment: Are you talking about accessing it through javascript or simply viewing it? If its simply viewing it, then go to Tools -> Developer Tools (Shift+Ctrl+I) then click on the Element tab and the Computed Style on the right hand side should show you the default values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I locate the default style sheet for a browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214378/how-can-i-locate-the-default-style-sheet-for-a-browser)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Take a look here for Chrome (Blink):

https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/main/third_party/blink/renderer/core/html/resources/html.css

For some other browsers: [Browsers' default CSS for HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/default-css-properties-of-html-elements/6867287#6867287)

Comment: Not going to -1 since it's inherent in the question to some degree, but this link will likely break at some point or become out of date.

Comment: @AlexMA: That link is always the most recent revision of `html.css`. It should work for a long time, unless WebKit moves away from Trac.