# Why is the color of a link black if we set it to `initial` and blue otherwise?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I was going through [mdn css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance) tutorial until i reach the `initial` value for color property for the `a` tag.

1- if we don't specify any color for the element it will be **blue**.

2-but if we set the color to `initial` it will be **black**.

For me both(not specifying any value and setting it to initial) look like the same thing (browser's default style sheet value for `a` color)
can some one please explain what is going on here?

```css
body {
  color: green;
}

.my-class-1 a {
  color: inherit;
}

.my-class-2 a {
  color: initial;
}

.my-class-3 a {
  color: unset;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Default <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
  <li class="my-class-1">Inherit the <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
  <li class="my-class-2">Reset the <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
  <li class="my-class-3">Unset the <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How can black and blue look the same?

Comment: i meant not specifying a value and setting it to initial.

Comment: I see in this order "blue","green", "black","green" colors there in the link example as I posted to the question as a snippet in chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that every css property has an [initial value](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-color)

for example:

`background-color` initial value is `Initial:   transparent`.

`background-image` initial value is `Initial:   none`.

in case of `color` property it is defined as `Initial:      depends on user agent`

which means it's up to the browser vendor to determine this value(it's **black** for google chrome).

so `color:initial` will apply the black color for the link.

but if we didn't specify any color property for `a` it will default to browser's [default style sheet value](https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css#L1204) for `a` color which is **blue** more precisely`-webkit-link`.